# Calculate the total amount using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, math

I'm trying to calculate the total amount using AngularJS.
want to calculate the total amount spent which is highlighted in above image.
Any Help would be appreciated.

[image]
**My HTML:-**

```
<body ng-app="nombre">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <form class="row" id="nombre">
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control col-9" id="Spentfor" name="Spentfor" placeholder="Spent for">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control col-3" id="SpentAmount" name="SpentAmount" placeholder="Spent Amount">
                  <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button id="add" class="btn" type="submit">Add</button> 
                  </div>
                </div>
            </form>     
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="container" ng-controller="budgetCtrl">
    <div class="row list" ng-repeat="kasu in panam">
        <div class="col-6"> {{ kasu.title }} </div>
        <div class="col-6 text-right total">
            {{ kasu.spent | currency:"₹" }}
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6"> Total Money spend </div>
        <div class="col-6 overalltotal"> {{ getTotal() }} </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

**My JS:-**

```
var nombre = angular.module('nombre', ['ngRoute', 'firebase']);

nombre.controller('budgetCtrl', ['$scope', 'money', '$firebaseObject', function($scope, money, $firebaseObject){
    money.then(function(data){
        $scope.cash = data;
        // $scope.pisa = data.desktop;
    });

    var ref = firebase.database().ref();
    $scope.panam = $firebaseObject(ref);
    var pa = $scope.panam;

    $("#nombre").submit(function() { 
        $(this), console.log("Submit to Firebase");
        var Spentfor = $("#Spentfor").val(),
            SpentAmount = $("#SpentAmount").val(),
            total = { title: Spentfor, spent: SpentAmount};
        alert(total);

        return ref.push().set(total).then(function() { 
            $("#Spentfor, #SpentAmount").val("");
        });

    });

    $scope.getTotal = function(){
        // edit here
    }

}]);

nombre.factory('money', ['$http', function($http){
    return $http.get('budget.json')
            .then(function(response){
               return data = response.data;
            }, function(error){
                alert('error');
            });
}]);
```

im trying to get it done through.

```
$scope.getTotal = function(){}
```

Above data is called from firebase. I'm trying to calculate the total amount spent using AngularJS. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to data you show in your HTML template, this should work :

```
$scope.getTotal = function(){
  let total = 0;
  $scope.panam.forEach(p => {
    total += parseFloat(p.spent);
  });
  return total;
}
```

Iterate all your items (`panam`), and add `spent` number to `total` you send back in your function `getTotal`.

Comment: its working. But it just add the values one after the other like 050120143143112201201502905029041. i want the get the total value.
@Zooly

Comment: I see, because your values are String. Edited my answer :)

Comment: I've added a `parseFloat` function before `p.spent` data

Comment: Yup, My mistake. It works like a charm. Thanks Buddy.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `getTotal` and pass the `pa`

```
let total =0;
$scope.getTotal = function(obj){
    obj.forEach(function(item){
     total += parseFloat(item.spent)
 })
}
var pa = $scope.panam;
$scope.getTotal(pa)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through and add it to the total

```
$scope.total = 0;
money.then(function(data){
        $scope.cash = data;

         // if cash is array of object
          $scope.getTotal();

    });
$scope.getTotal = function(){
    $scope.cash.forEach((val) => {
             $scope.total += val.spent;
          })
}
```